# Venn diagram in R by taking a matrix as input

Tags: r, venn-diagram

Suppose I have 4 sets A,B,C,D each having 40 elements. I don't know the elements of these 4 sets but i know how many elements are common among these sets.

The matrix which shows the number of common elements are :

```
    A   B   C   D
A  40   21  33  38
B  21   40  25  31
C  33   25  40  27  
D  38   31  27  40
```

To understand better:

There are 21 common element between set A and B, 25 between B and C and so on ...

How can i generate 4 way venn diagram in R?

Comment: Should the diagram only represent pairwise interactions? I don't think there is enough info to tell how many elements are in common among three or more sets. Then maybe a Venn diagram isn't the best way to represent that data. Instead, you could use an undirected graph, where the vertices will be your sets and the edges will be the number of items in common.

Comment: Dear Flodel, based on your comment, I could able to understand that it is not possible to draw venn diagram for 3 or more sets for the information i have. Rather i would try alternate method like undirected graph which you suggested. Thanks a lot

Comment: There's a good guide here: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/venn.htm
The `limma` package handles venn diagrams of up to 5 sets.

Comment: @Manetheran, using the link you posted, the OP has no way of telling the number (`22`) at the center of the first graph shown there.

Comment: can someone tell me how you would generally describe the above matrix? Is there a name for such a thing?

Comment: Possible relevant thread here with a case example http://stackoverflow.com/q/40563697/54964